# Run 'code .' when you type "code ," in bash or terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, zsh

I often accidentally type "code ," when opening vs code in a hurry. I want a bash or zsh script that can open vs code in the current directory when i type code .

I tried a function in my aliases but it was recursively calling itself. is there anyway to make an alias with two arguments?

Comment: Functions take arguments. Aliases do not - they merely replace text. Try a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple function:

```
code () {
    command code "${1:-.}"
}
```

lets you just type `code` (no argument at all) to use the current directory, without preventing you from passing a different directory if you need to.

(This needs adjusting if `code` already has some special meaning if you don't pass an argument, or if you need to consider a more complicated case like `.`/`,` being the first non-option argument, rather than the first (if not only) argument.)

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed.